# Is mysql insert from subquery atomic?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, atomic, insert-select

If I do a query like

```
insert into sometable b + 10 from select b from (select b from sometable order by id desc limit 1)
```

Is this operation atomic? That is, would it be possible for an insert into sometable to change the value of b AFTER is has been queried, but before the insert completes, causing the insert to get the wrong value?

Comment: Sometimes - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that it is not. You can lock it to make sure it doesn't change:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (b)
SELECT b+10
FROM sometable
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
LOCK IN SHARE MODE
```

Comment: "My guess" is not an answer. Anyone can guess.